# The type 'ReportViewer' exists in both 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, and 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=15.0.0.0

Tags: c#, devexpress

I am upgrading my applicaton from devExpress 12.1 to 23.3

Because of this i have migrated from packages.config to reference

`The type 'ReportViewer' exists in both 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' and 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91'`

I am unable to find the Microsof.ReportViewer.Webform version 11.0.0.0 by ctrl + shift+ F.

Here is my project.csproj file

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc">
      <Version>5.2.3</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor">
      <Version>3.2.9</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization">
      <Version>1.1.3</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages">
      <Version>3.2.9</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Abstractions">
      <Version>2.2.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Core">
      <Version>2.2.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization">
      <Version>2.2.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy">
      <Version>2.2.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions">
      <Version>2.2.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.Abstractions">
      <Version>2.2.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http">
      <Version>2.2.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions">
      <Version>2.2.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions">
      <Version>2.2.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features">
      <Version>2.2.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch">
      <Version>2.2.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions">
      <Version>2.2.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core">
      <Version>2.2.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json">
      <Version>2.2.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCaching.Abstractions">
      <Version>2.2.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing">
      <Version>2.2.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Abstractions">
      <Version>2.2.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities">
      <Version>2.2.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces">
      <Version>7.0.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform">
      <Version>2.0.1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CSharp">
      <Version>4.7.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.DotNet.PlatformAbstractions">
      <Version>2.1.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration">
      <Version>7.0.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions">
      <Version>7.0.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions">
      <Version>7.0.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json">
      <Version>7.0.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection">
      <Version>2.2.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions">
      <Version>2.2.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel">
      <Version>2.1.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Abstractions">
      <Version>7.0.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical">
      <Version>7.0.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.FileSystemGlobbing">
      <Version>7.0.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions">
      <Version>2.2.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions">
      <Version>2.2.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.ObjectPool">
      <Version>2.2.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options">
      <Version>2.2.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives">
      <Version>7.0.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation">
      <Version>3.2.3</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Net.Http">
      <Version>2.0.20710</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers">
      <Version>2.2.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms">
      <Version>150.1586.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.SqlServer.Types">
      <Version>14.0.314.76</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure">
      <Version>1.0.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Modernizr">
      <Version>2.6.2</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json">
      <Version>13.0.3</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="popper.js">
      <Version>1.14.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="ReportViewerForMvc4">
      <Version>1.1.2</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="System-Web-Helpers.dll">
      <Version>1.0.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Buffers">
      <Version>4.5.1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="System.ComponentModel.Annotations">
      <Version>4.5.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient">
      <Version>4.8.5</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource">
      <Version>4.5.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="System.IO">
      <Version>4.3.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Memory">
      <Version>4.5.5</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Net.Http">
      <Version>4.0.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Numerics.Vectors">
      <Version>4.5.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Runtime">
      <Version>4.3.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe">
      <Version>6.0.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation">
      <Version>4.0.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms">
      <Version>4.3.1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding">
      <Version>4.3.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives">
      <Version>4.3.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates">
      <Version>4.3.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Text.Encodings.Web">
      <Version>7.0.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Text.Json">
      <Version>7.0.3</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions">
      <Version>4.5.4</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="System.ValueTuple">
      <Version>4.5.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Twitter.Bootstrap">
      <Version>3.0.1.1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="WebGrease">
      <Version>1.5.2</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms.140.340.80\lib\net40\Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.ReportViewer.DataVisualization, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms.140.340.80\lib\net40\Microsoft.ReportViewer.DataVisualization.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Design, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms.140.340.80\lib\net40\Microsoft.ReportViewer.Design.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms.140.340.80\lib\net40\Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebDesign, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms.140.340.80\lib\net40\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebDesign.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms.140.340.80\lib\net40\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Here is my web.config package reference

```
                <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />
                <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />
            </assemblies>
```

Runtime version specific

```
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-13.0.0.0" newVersion="13.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <!--<dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-11.0.0.0" newVersion="11.0.0.0" />
              </dependentAssembly>-->
            <!--<dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.ReportViewer.DataVisualization" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-14.0.0.0" newVersion="14.0.0.0" />
              </dependentAssembly>
              <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-11.0.0.0" newVersion="11.0.0.0" />
              </dependentAssembly>-->
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Types" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-14.0.0.0" newVersion="14.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Text.Json" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-7.0.0.3" newVersion="7.0.0.3" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-14.0.0.0" newVersion="14.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <!--<dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.0" newVersion="4.2.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>-->
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="DocumentFormat.OpenXml" publicKeyToken="8fb06cb64d019a17" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.18.0.0" newVersion="2.18.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <!--<dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.0" newVersion="4.2.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>-->
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-7.0.0.0" newVersion="7.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Buffers" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.3.0" newVersion="4.0.3.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Text.Encodings.Web" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-7.0.0.0" newVersion="7.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Abstractions" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-7.0.0.0" newVersion="7.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Memory" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.1.2" newVersion="4.0.1.2" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-7.0.0.0" newVersion="7.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.1" newVersion="4.2.0.1" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <!--<dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>-->
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
```

Here is the nuget packages picture attached
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing was that my application also included

Just delete this or Remove everything in web.config with Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms and open .csproj comment all the other package than Microsoft.ReportViewer check if error gone then uncomment one by one.

```
<PackageReference Include="ReportViewerForMvc4">
   <Version>1.1.2</Version>
 </PackageReference>
```

Which cause Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForm version conflicts error of Installed and 11.0.0.0

Commenting every package reference one by one and came to know that this was the problem.